# PHP Mod rewrite for user accounts

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I've been searching for how I can rewrite a url that is like this:

http://www.example.com/profile.php?username=test

to something like this:

http://www.example.com/user/test

Also, I would like to rewrite other urls that are like this:

(feed page) 'url'/profile.php?username=test&page=feed
(videos page) 'url'/profile.php?username=test&page=videos

to something like this:

(feed page) 'url'/user/test/feed
(videos page) 'url'/user/test/videos

I read up on this and couldn't really find anything to my liking. I really don't understand mod_rewrite that well and would be thrilled if someone could explain it to me using the examples above. Thanks!

Comment: Do you understand regular expressions, or at least have a good idea of what they are? If not, that’s step 1.

Comment: I kind of understand them, but could do a bit more practice with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^user/([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)$ profile.php?username=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Would this also do the one for http://www.example.com/profile.php?username=test&page=home to http://www.example.com/test/home

Comment: see my updated code, don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you